# Why is this CSS selector taking precedence over more specific selector?

Tags: css, css-modules, css-specificity, react-css-modules

I have this in my React app:

```
<Nav>
   <BasicBtn>Basic button</BasicBtn>
   <MainBtn>Main button</MainBtn>
</Nav>
```

The font size for buttons is set globally:

```
// globals.css

button {
   font-size: 24px; 
}
```

**What I want to do is to reduce BasicBtn's font size via the Nav component to 20px, meaning I want it to be smaller when wrapped inside Nav; however, I do NOT want to affect MainBtn, whose font size is set to 14px in its own module**. What happens, instead, is that the font size set in Nav overrides the font size set in MainBtn, so MainBtn is 20px as well instead of 14px.

This is my Nav component:

```
// Nav.js 

import styles from "./Nav.module.css"

const Nav = ( { children } ) => <nav className={ styles.Nav }>{ children }</nav>

export default Nav 

// Nav.module.css

.Nav button {
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

This is my BasicBtn component:

```
// BasicBtn.js

import styles from "./BasicBtn.module.css"
import cn from "classnames"

const BasicBtn = ( { children, extraStyles } ) => {
   return <button className={ cn( styles.BasicBtn, extraStyles ) }>{ children }</button>
}

export default BasicBtn 

// BasicBtn.module.css

.BasicBtn {
   padding: 10px; 
   background: green; 
   color: white; 
}
```

This is my MainBtn component:

```
// MainBtn.js

import styles from "./MainBtn.module.css"
import BasicBtn from "../BasicBtn"

const MainBtn = ( { children } ) => <BasicBtn extraStyles={ styles.MainBtn }>{ children }</BasicBtn>

export default MainBtn 

// MainBtn.module.css

.MainBtn {
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

This is the generated HTML:

```
<nav class="Nav_Nav__WC_B6">
    <button class="BasicBtn_BasicBtn__q_G1X">Basic button</button>
    <button class="BasicBtn_BasicBtn__q_G1X MainBtn_MainBtn__92Bu4">Main button</button>
</nav>
```

And these, in this order, are the CSS rules that I get when clicking on the generated MainBTN (copied from DevTools):

```
.Nav_Nav__WC_B6 button {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.MainBtn_MainBtn__92Bu4 {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.BasicBtn_BasicBtn__q_G1X {
    padding: 10px;
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Shouldn't the `.MainBtn_MainBtn__92Bu4` selector take precedence over `.Nav_Nav__WC_B6 button`, seeing as it is more specific?

Comment: `.MainBtn_MainBtn__92Bu4` is _not_ more specific than `.Nav_Nav__WC_B6 button`, but it is exactly the other way around. https://specificity.keegan.st

Comment: See [CSS Specificity (MDN Docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Selecting one class is just one class, no matter how many important words or underscores it has. Class AND a tag name: That's more specific than just a class. See link to documentation for more examples.